# Python3 Asyncio HTTP Server: StreamReader Get Uploaded File

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

How can I get a file uploaded to a server using asyncio.start_server?
I sent a file using CURL by this command:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "data=@server.py" http://localhost:8888
```

And the result of the StremReader is:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: curl/7.35.0\r\nHost: localhost:8888\r\nAccept: */*\r\nContent-Length: 7673\r\nExpect: 100-continue\r\nContent-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------ea4b0f3e04ac89ad\r\n\r\n
```

My source code: https://github.com/carlosmaniero/asyncio_server/blob/master/server.py.

Comment: You can see example of multipart reader/writer in aiohttp  https://github.com/KeepSafe/aiohttp/blob/master/aiohttp/multipart.py

Comment: There's a **huge** gap between `asyncio. start_server` and HTTP file uploading logic. You may want to look into some existing frameworks such as `aiohttp`, or do more research on the HTTP protocol yourself.